# Disabling LOCAL INFILE in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, security, mariadb

In an article about securing MySQL they recommended disabling LOCAL INFILE unless I need it.
http://www.greensql.com/content/mysql-security-best-practices-hardening-mysql-tips

I would like to do the same in MariaDB but the following config line doesn't seem to work in MariaDB (used to work in Mysql):

```
set-variable=local-infile=0
```

Does anybody know how to disable it? Or maybe it doesn't have a runtime config switch and needs to be compiled with a specific configure flag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `set-variable` method of setting variables [was deprecated in MySQL 5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html), and instead you can set the variable by name directly in `my.cnf`.

This works for me in MariaDB 5.5.34:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
```

[MariaDB's documentation on setting server variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/) recommends setting values in `my.cnf` using the format

```
variable-name = "value"
```

Comment: This did not work for me. When I put it under the [client-server] section in mariadb.cnf it finally took hold. Setting local-infile=0 under [mysqld] in my MariaDB would not yield a disabled LOCAL INFILE. I'm using Distrib 10.0.29-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64).